# Ayehu eyeshare : Running workflow from just the Executor, without the Studio

Tags: scripting, automation, workflow, runbook

I have *Ayehu Eyeshare Studio* installed on one machine and have the *Executor* installed on another. In no way, these two machines are connected via a shared network.

Is there a way by which I can develop workflows on one machine and run it via the executor on the other?

Note: The Studio is not present on the machine, where the executor is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Ayehu Support team with this query. As of now, there no way to achieve this. The Ayehu Eyeshare Studio and the Executor must be connected for this to be achieved.